# Finding the matrix ${\left[ T \right]_E}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Let the matrix ${\left[ T \right]_{B \to E}}$, the matrix where:

$${\left[ T \right]_{B \to E}}{\left[ v \right]_E} = {\left[ {T(v)} \right]_B}$$

It's given that:
$${\left[ T \right]_{B \to E}} = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 3  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

I need to find what ${\left[ T \right]_E}$ is.

So, by definition of ${\left[ T \right]_{B \to E}}$:

$${\left[ T \right]_{B \to E}} = \left( {\matrix{
   {T{{\left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   0  \cr 
 } } \right)}_B}} & {T{{\left( {\matrix{
   0  \cr 
   1  \cr 
 } } \right)}_B}}  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

Hence,
$$T{\left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   0  \cr 
 } } \right)_B} = \left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   1  \cr 
 } } \right),T{\left( {\matrix{
   0  \cr 
   1  \cr 
 } } \right)_B} = \left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   3  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

Because $E$ is the standard basis, we deduce that:

$${\left[ T \right]_E} = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1  \cr 
   1 & 3  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

**Is that right? I am little bit confused by this material**